# Deserialization of general XML

Tags: xml-serialization, c++-cli

First a warning, I'm a complete n00b at deserialization. That said, I have some XML that I'm receiving from another system in a message queue. I have no control over the XML.

The XML encapsulates the message, and it contains a header and a payload. The header contains the message type, so I need to parse out the header first, then parse out the message contents, and I was hoping to do this with the same XmlReader. (I don't know if the XmlReader stream remembers its location, or if the Reader closes the stream and I need to reopen it, but this should be achievable, yes?)

The first problem I encounter is how to tell the Header Class that the element name I want is inside. Creating a message class is problematic, because I won't know what type of message it is until I deserialize the header. Look at this XML:

```
<SCHED_MSG>
    <HEADER>
      <SOURCE_IDENT_TEXT>MES.PRIM_SCHED</SOURCE_IDENT_TEXT>
      <GEN_EST>2011-12-21T14:01:48.876-05:00</GEN_EST>
      <ISL_MSG_IDENT_TEXT>REL_SCHED_PID_MHS</ISL_MSG_IDENT_TEXT>
    </HEADER>
</SCHED_MSG>
```

If I label the XmlRootElement ElementName = "HEADER", I get an exception because that's not the root of the XML. (Is there some way to tell it that the root is "SCHED_MSG.HEADER"?) If I use SCHED_MSG as the header, I can't seem to get to the element GEN_EST. (Again, is there some way to tell dot Net that the XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "HEADER.GEN_EST")?)

Note: I've removed the message from this, but it would go after the  and before the  tags. I receive the message from the queue as char *, which use to initialize to a System::String, then use the string to create a StringReader, and feed the StringReader to the XmlReader.Create(). The XmlReader is, in turn, passed to the XmlSerializer constructor using the type of this class:

```
[Serializable]
//[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "SCHED_MHS_MSG")]
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "SCHED_MHS_MSG.DOFASCO_HEADER")]
public ref class DofascoHeader
{
public:
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "GEN_EST")]
    System::DateTime GenerationTime;

    //[XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "ISL_MSG_IDENT_TEXT")]
    //String ^MessageName;
};
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone else is trying to do this, here's at least one option that works.

```
XmlReader ^ messageData = XmlReader::Create(mqTestStream);
try
{
    while (messageData->Read())
    {
        if (
            (messageData->NodeType == XmlNodeType::Element)
            &&
            (messageData->Name == "HEADER")
            )
        {

            System::Xml::Serialization::XmlSerializer ^HeadParser = gcnew System::Xml::Serialization::XmlSerializer(Header::typeid);

            Header ^MyHead;
            MyHead = dynamic_cast<Header^>(HeadParser->Deserialize(messageData));
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch(XmlException ^e)
{
    Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
}
```